# How to find path from getTree function from root to leaf in randomForest in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

The `getTree` function in randomForest package in R displays the structure of the a particular tree used in the random forest.

Here is an example on the iris dataset

```
library(randomForest)
data(iris)
rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., iris)
getTree(rf, 1)
```

This shows the output of tree #1 of 500:

```
   left daughter right daughter split var split point status prediction
1              2              3         3        2.50      1          0
2              0              0         0        0.00     -1          1
3              4              5         4        1.65      1          0
4              6              7         4        1.35      1          0
5              8              9         3        4.85      1          0
6              0              0         0        0.00     -1          2
7             10             11         2        3.10      1          0
8             12             13         4        1.55      1          0
9              0              0         0        0.00     -1          3
10             0              0         0        0.00     -1          3
11             0              0         0        0.00     -1          2
12            14             15         2        2.55      1          0
13             0              0         0        0.00     -1          2
14            16             17         2        2.35      1          0
15             0              0         0        0.00     -1          3
16             0              0         0        0.00     -1          3
17             0              0         0        0.00     -1          2
```

Now my main aim is to find the path from Node 1 to a terminal node (in these cases 2,6,9,10 etc)

Is there a common algorithm or code I can use?

Path for 9 will be   1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 9
Path for 10 will be  1 -> 3 -> 6 -> 10

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: This is overall a good question, but you should use `set.seed()` to ensure a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this via recursion -- something like:

```
library(randomForest)
data(iris)
set.seed(123) # for reproducibility
rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., iris)

some_tree <- getTree(rf, 1)

some_tree

get_path_to_node <- function(tree, child){   
  parent <- which(tree[,'left daughter']==child | tree[,'right daughter']==child)
  if( parent==1 ) return(paste(parent, child,   sep='->'))
  return( paste(get_path_to_node(tree, child=parent), child, sep='->' ) )    
}

get_path_to_node(some_tree, 5)
```

gives you `1->3->5`

**Explanation:**  We start with a node `j`.  We can find out what its "parent" is by finding out which row has `left daughter` equal to `j` or `right daughter` equal to `j`.  We then repeat the process for its parent, and so forth, until we find that the parent is 1, which by definition is the root.  We use `paste` with `sep='->'` to build the chain as we go.

Comment: thanks, do you have any further edit on how can I find the least common ancestor of two nodes using your algorithm?

Comment: @rmania you're welcome -- if this answers the question as written please show it some love (check to accept, upvotes welcome :) -- and post the next question separately

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 thanks I have posted another question similar to this one if you can help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107978/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-instances-used-for-classification-in-random-forest-tre

Answer (score 0):

This answer only *dilates* the answer from user 'Enprofylline' in terms of finding <strike>least</strike> lowest common ancestor.

```
library(randomForest)
data(iris)
set.seed(123) # for reproducibility
rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., iris)

some_tree <- getTree(rf, 1)

some_tree

get_path_to_node_v2 <- function(tree, child){   
  parent <- which(tree[,'left daughter']==child | tree[,'right daughter']==child)
  if( parent==1 ) return(c(1,child))
  return(c(get_path_to_node_v2(tree, child=parent),child))    
}
lowest_ancest <- function(tree,child_A,child_B) {
  path_A = get_path_to_node_v2(tree,child_A)
  path_B = get_path_to_node_v2(tree,child_B)
  max(path_A[(path_A %in% path_B)])
}
lowest_ancest(some_tree,11,15)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have posted another question related to this one, if you can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107978/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-instances-used-for-classification-in-random-forest-tre